# Как на Python нажать Разрешить в Веб Push-уведомления в Firefox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firefox

Использую селениум но если им такое можно провернуть то как, а если нет то чем?
ИЛИ как можно имитировать нажатие, по типу "навестись мышкой" но кодом, чтобы программа сама без участия человека. Бонусом будет если в режиме мультипоточноcти всё будет работать без "приколов", ну это бонус, главное нажать на кнопочку :)
Доброго времени суток!

Comment: Зайдите с другой стороны - разрешение пушей добавляет запись куда то в профиле (например в `permissions.sqlite` пишет разрешение `desktop-notification`). Отследите где куда и пишите напрямую в профиль заранее.